# How to get notification in your android app, if update available in android app store?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

I developed an android application and I have put it in android app store by paying 25 bucks. However some people are using my application in their device. I wanna know, if I upload     the updated version of my app in app store then how user finds that out?

I found out some links on the same context in android developer site and all but didn't technically clear out my understanding. Basically I want to know, 
how android app update mechanism works? 
How device gets notification of available updates?

Please provide some clarity as a developer point of view/ code level.

Reffered links:

### [Android app update mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17465845/android-app-update-mechanism) http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/versioning.html#minsdkversion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.
Try [this](https://github.com/rampo/UpdateChecker) code hope thats what you want.